# A reference exist from an object of class A to an object of class B. If A is serialized, do we might lose the object from B?

Tags: java, serialization, reference, garbage-collection

My question is quite simple, really:

Suppose we have a class A, whom its only field is a reference to object from class B:

```
private B b;.
```

Lets assume that only an object from A points to the reference of b.

Now suppose we serialized the A object.

So now, apparently nothing points to object b (of type B). Will garbage-collector might "kill" b? and if it does - didn't we lose information of A?

Will A still have a legit reference to b when it will be deserialized?

I would be grateful for an explanation about this confusing situation. Thanks!

Comment: When you serialize A, you only create a bunch of bytes. The operation does not change `A` in any way. When you use these bytes to deserialize `A`, you get a new instance of `A`, a copy. This will again not affect the old `A` nor its `b` reference. The copy of `A` will have a reference to a copy of `B`, as explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57746045/2711488).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your class `B` implements `Serializable` as well, serializing the instance of `A` will also serialize its nested object `b`.

The original instance referenced by `b` will get garbage collected if nothing else points to it and to your original instance of `A`. But if you deserialize `A`, it will also deserialize the nested `b`, creating a new instance of both `A` and `B` in the process.

If you do not wish `b` to be serialized here, you need to mark the reference as `transient`. Deserializing `A` will then have `null` assigned to `b`.

Comment: Thanks @Crush K. Rool. It makes a lot of sense